# uwsgi + flask: Find ini file with which uwsgi was launched

Tags: flask, config, uwsgi

I am creating a flask application with uwsgi. I have 2 config INIs development.ini and production.ini.

uwsgi development.ini

Is there any way for to me to know which config file was used for launch with uwsgi inside the flask app?

I am using flask-iniconfig to use the same config ini for flask config values. I would like to avoid having to change the config file name in uwsgi launch and flask app.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use an environment variable:

```
APP_CONFIG=development.ini uwsgi $APP_CONFIG
```

Then, in your flask app, simply load the same file:

```
from os import environ

app = Flask(__name__)
# ... snip ...

config_file_name = environ.get("APP_CONFIG", "development.ini")
config_from_ini_file(app, config_file_name)
```

Comment: sorry forgot to mention that, I am already using environment variable. Was just wondering if there is some direct method.